# Bash script stops execution of ffmpeg in while loop - why?

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, ffmpeg

I have this bash script for converting `.mp4` video to `.mp3` audio.
It runs, but does the loop only once, though there are more mp4 files in `/home/myname/mp4dir`.

The script converts the first `.mp4` file it finds to `.mp3`, unless there is already an `.mp3` file. This should be done in a loop, but after the first call to ffmpeg the script stops.

Why?

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/myname/mp4dir -name "*.mp4" | while read f
do
        fOut=`echo $f | sed s/mp4/mp3/`
        echo "convert $f => $fOut"
        if ! test -f $fOut
        then
                ffmpeg -i $f -vn -f mp3 $fOut
        fi
done
```

Comment: Does it work if you replace the loop body with `echo $f`?

Comment: Yes, all .mp4 files are listed. The script stops after the first ffmpeg execution. If I comment this out and replace it by an echo, it runs for all .mp4 files.

Comment: What do you see when you run the script with `bash -x youscript.sh`?  Does the `ffmpeg` command complete?

Comment: With `bash -x youscript.sh` the loop executes more than once; the output of several ffmpeg calls shows. What's the difference?

Comment: Edit: Sorry, my fault: The behaviour is the same as with direct call to the script: It executes only once.

Comment: Since the loop runs just once, what are the first two file names output by the `find` command?

Comment: The first found files are: `/home/myname/ted/download.ted.com/talks/EdGavagan_2012P.mp4
/home/myname/ted/download.ted.com/talks/LeslieChang_2012G.mp4
/home/myname/ted/download.ted.com/talks/IvanKrastev_2012G.mp4`

Comment: It sounds like `ffmpeg` is reading from standard input, so that the first call consumes the rest of the `find` output. What happens if you add `< /dev/null` to the end of the `ffmpeg` command? (Just guessing, as I see no reason why it should read from standard input when you use the `-i` flag.)

Comment: Also, what is the *exact* code you are running? Your `find` command above searches "/home/myname/mp4dir", but "mp4dir" does not appear in the files you listed above.

Comment: how big are the files? My limited experience with converting audio/video files is that it takes a lot longer that I would expect (like). Maybe its still running? Good luck.

Comment: Maybe the ffmpeg does an exec

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain why you downvoted the question? -- @chepner: `mp4dir` is only a placeholder for the actual path, as you correctly observed. It is not in the actual script code.

Comment: @AlexMonthy Always make sure that whatever code you post is *exactly* what you are running to test the solution. You might think a difference is irrelevant, but it might not be. Whenever I see output that disagrees with the posted code, I have to wonder what *else* is different, and if that might not be the key to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments we got that there actually are input files you are looping over (of what kind soever) and that `ffmpeg` at least starts once. Then, you are stuck.

Add

```
&> ffmpeg.outerr < /dev/null
```

to your `ffmpeg` command and monitor the file `ffmpeg.outerr` while your "loop", i.e. ffmpeg, executes. It will tell you what the problem is. Either you can solve this problem yourself, or you come back to stackoverflow with this *ffmpeg-specific problem* using the tag `ffmpeg`.

Comment: The `< /dev/null` does the trick. Only I don't know why. The log file does not show any errors, just the regular output of ffmpeg. But with the input redirection the loop runs as intended.

Comment: The ffmpeg solution is to add the `-nostdin` flag to the `ffmpeg` command

Answer (score 13):

The answer is to add `-nostdin` to ffmpeg (wouldn't answer to an old question like this, but still tops on related Google searches).

Answer (score 4):

try this
in terminal

create bash nohup.sh and paste in this

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
 /var/www/bash/Someother-bash-script-goes-here.sh
 sleep 60
done
```

in terminal type where nohup.sh is located

```
nohup sh nohup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

nohup, will execute every 60 seconds, you can grep service check like this

```
 #!/bin/sh
SERVICE='ffmpeg'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE service running, will not bother ffmpeg yet"
else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running"
    echo "$SERVICE is not running!" | /var/www/bash/start_service.sh
fi
```