# ffmpeg: Execute command in while loop

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm trying to execute a ffmpeg command on a list of video files, stored in an ascii file.

I simply tried to combine the reading of filenames with a while loop but it seems not to work. 
For some reason every video filename gets cropped

```
while read p; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$p" [some options] ;
done < filelist.txt
```

Any idea why this is happening?

filelist.txt looks like this:

```
video1.mp4
video2.mp4
video3.mp4
[...]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of `filelist.txt` ?

Comment: weirdly the same command is working fine when I use `for f in $(find .); do ...` instead. I used both commands frequently and interchangeably, it's weird that `while` fails in this situation

Comment: I have seen this problem before: `ffmpeg` reads the same stdin `while` is reading. Use `ffmpeg ... < /dev/null` or `-nostdin`.  There should be a duplicate somewhere out there. If you find it, please link it.

Comment: Found the duplicate: [bash script stops execution in while loop - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543628/bash-script-stops-execution-in-while-loop-why) and [execute ffmpeg command in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21634088/6770384)